# Website redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My question is quite simple. I have my main page (www.domain.com/index.php)

1. Is there a way to redirect the user to /index.php when he only types www.domain.com?
2. And also remove the index.php from the url when he's on it?

I checked a bit about .htaccess, but none of the tricks seem to do the job.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here's my .htaccess:

```
# To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
# suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini

DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes
```

As you can see, I put DirectoryIndex index.php in it, but doesn't change it :(

Comment: 1 & 2 sort of conflict, don't they? "Go over there, but don't show that you're there". Other than making index.php your default document in Apache (using DirectoryIndex as Hamish answered below), you can't really control what the user sees in the address bar.

Comment: @Marc, of course you can – that's what HTTP redirects are for. `index.php` → `/` external, `/` → `index.php` internal, makes perfect sense :)

Comment: hehe I mean: User types www.domain.com, he is redirected to www.domain.com/index.php but it stays www.domain.com. Basically, index.php becomes the default page.

Comment: That's what DirectoryIndex is for then. it specifies which file(s) Apache should use as the default document when the URL doesn't directly specify one (as www.domain.com and www.domain.com/) don't.

Comment: I dit that, but it doesn't seems to work. I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: i Search  and find related this.
Its hepl you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539752/redirect-function/13539808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

in your .htaccess

When the user types **www.domain.com** it'll take **index.php** as default index page and won't be display in the address

Comment: hummm doesn't seem to work. I wrote my .htaccess in my question.

Comment: @Elggetto : Doesn't work isn't a real answer. What does it do when you go on **www.domain.com** ?

Comment: Yeah sorry. It goes straight to **www.domain.com/index.html** (I have a temporary index.html just for tests)

Comment: Well, are you sure there's a **index.php** page? Usually apache+PHP server is configure to use index.php and if absent index.html as default index page. .htaccess file may override this or not depending on your apache configuration. If you don't have access to that information and are sure that **index.php** is here, in the good folder, I advise you to get rid of **index.html** and using, let's say **test.html** for tests ;)

Comment: ...easy as that. Thanks a lot. I only needed to delete **index.html** for this to work!

Answer (score 0):

in the Domain control panel mention Start / Index page as index.php.
Usually index.html/htm is the default page. 
You will find these option under site proerties.

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect / http:/your.domain.php/index.php
```

Comment: This will display `http:/your.domain.php/index.php` in the address, and the OP wants `http:/your.domain.php/`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   # URL path corresponding to this directory
RewriteRule (^|.*/)index\.php$ $1 [R]
```